# Accessing Microsoft Office Events from Python (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint equiv lib?)

Tags: python, c#, powerpoint

I'm hoping to implement Scott Hanselman's [PowerPoint to OBS Scene Switcher](https://github.com/shanselman/PowerPointToOBSSceneSwitcher) with python instead of C#, as I don't know C#, don't want to install .NET on my Macs, and just want to do it in python. I have a feeling I would struggle more with the .NET stuff than learning C#, as the language looks pretty straight forward syntactically.

The issue I'm stuck on implementing is that the C# code uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint to detect the SlideShowNextSlide event that PowerPoint signals, but it is an internal event.

I've searched but been unable to find a python library that would allow similar access. ***Does anybody know of one?***

Would hope that Microsoft, which seems to be adopting python a bit more, would create the library, but keeping it in C# also assures a bit of capture back to .NET.

Comment: [help/on-topic]: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is probably "No", unless you count using IronPython to access the "live" connection between a running PowerPoint application instance on a Windows machine.

`python-pptx` reads and writes PPTX *files*, but has no connection to a running PowerPoint instance, as does, say VBA running under Windows. Consequently it is not going to have any knowledge of what is happening in a running PowerPoint application, like an "I'm changing to slide X now" event.

The IronPython approach would probably work, but it's hard to do with the paucity of documentation on how the Microsoft PowerPoint object model is mapped into Python object names. Basically every line is a struggle to somehow reverse engineer how to access the object you're interested in. Might be worth a try though if that environment otherwise appeals to you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's even harder since I'm trying to do it on macOS. I'm working on an approach using AppleScript, controlling the changes of slides and the script running via hotkey. There is that same paucity of documentation on getting PowerPoint info via AS.